# Why is my heroku app and local app different?

Tags: express, heroku

I have no idea how to explain this or what to post but maybe the easiest way is through images. Here is a look at my locally hosted website: [image]

Simple enough right? It goes off screen if the viewport isn't wide enough for it. Now here is my heroku app: 
[image]
This isn't the only issue. There are other problems too. Like images not reacting to media queries. Or when they do react they react in a different way. The ak image isn't even in the same place. And some other images are of different sizes compared to what I'm seeing.
I have tried deleting my git commit history, I have deleted my master branch and redid it. I just don't know what's left to try. Any advice would be very VERY much appreciated.

Update: I have since tried deploying to a different app. And it worked just fine! But how do I reset the heroku app that i have right now without changing the domain settings?

Comment: You should look in your browser's developer console. I'd suspect that some CSS file or something isn't loading correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have figured it out! It was cloudflare SSL that was the issue. It was mixing cached data with non-cached data and turning the whole page into a pile of wack.